# Erro - teste de Fisher no R

Tags: r

Tenho tentado realizar um teste de Fisher com pares de variáveis de um banco que tem 823 casos. Estou usando o pacote gmodels. Entretanto, aparece o seguinte erro:

```
Error in fisher.test(t, alternative = "two.sided") : 
  FEXACT error 7(location). LDSTP=18510 is too small for this problem,
  (pastp=17.2051, ipn_0:=ipoin[itp=71]=329, stp[ipn_0]=14.8098).
Increase workspace or consider using 'simulate.p.value=TRUE'
Além disso: Warning message:
In chisq.test(t, correct = FALSE, ...) :
  Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

Já tentei contornar usando a função `> memory.limit(25000)` e  `>fisher.test(input_table, workspace = 2e8)`, mas sem sucesso.Também tentei usar a função sugerida no erro (`>simulate.p.value=TRUE`), porém não deu certo. Alguma ideia sobre como poderia resolver? Ou seria um problema da memória do próprio computador?

Obrigada!

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que o teste de Fisher calcula fatoriais e a função fatorial cresce muito depressa. Com 823 casos, terá um denominador em que entra

```
factorial(823)
#[1] Inf
```

Para realizar testes das variáveis duas a duas, pode usar `combn`.

```r
# só correr os testes para estas colunas
cols <- 3:20

set.seed(1234)
res_list <- combn(dados[cols], 2, FUN = \(x) {
  fisher.test(x[[1]], x[[2]], simulate.p.value = TRUE)
}, simplify = FALSE)

# para se saber quais as variáveis testadas
names(res_list) <- combn(names(dados[cols]), 2, FUN = paste, collapse = "_")

# o número de combinações das variáveis duas a duas é
# igual ao comprimento da lista de resultados
choose(ncol(dados[cols]), 2)
#> [1] 153
length(res_list)
#> [1] 153
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Cada membro da lista `res_list` é um objeto tal como descrito em `help("fisher.test")`, secção Value.

```r
str(res_list[[1]])
#> List of 4
#>  $ p.value    : num 0.713
#>  $ alternative: chr "two.sided"
#>  $ method     : chr "Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data with simulated p-value\n\t (based on 2000 replicates)"
#>  $ data.name  : chr "x[[1]] and x[[2]]"
#>  - attr(*, "class")= chr "htest"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Para ver os resultados pode-se usar o operador de extração `[[` e para extrair todos os p-values, usa-se um ciclo `sapply`.

```r
res_list[[1]]
#> 
#>  Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data with simulated p-value (based on
#>  2000 replicates)
#> 
#> data:  x[[1]] and x[[2]]
#> p-value = 0.7126
#> alternative hypothesis: two.sided

pvals <- sapply(res_list, `[[`, 'p.value')
head(pvals)
#>      V3_V4      V3_V5      V3_V6      V3_V7      V3_V8      V3_V9 
#> 0.71264368 0.04947526 0.21889055 0.96501749 0.73513243 0.96601699
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

## Dados de teste

```r
set.seed(2022)
dados <- replicate(20, {
  n <- sample(2:10, 1)
  p <- runif(n)
  repeat({
    s <- sample(letters[1:n], 823, replace = TRUE, prob = p/sum(p))
    if(length(unique(s)) >= 2L) break
  })
  s
})
dados <- as.data.frame(dados)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>